# Remotely reg add via batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm attempting to add a font to a remote computer on my network.

I have successfully transferred the file to the fonts folder on the remote computer but I seem to be getting the following error when trying to update registry and I can't seem to figure out why it wont work as all computers in the TXT file are connected to the network, there are no blank spaces in the file and the reg add adds the entry on my own computer if I remove "%%i" from the script.

Error: ERROR: The network path was not found.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (C:\Users\adm-acoombes\Documents\scripts\AV-Update.txt) DO (
robocopy C:\Users\User1\Documents\FONT \\%%i\c$\Windows\Test
reg.exe Add "\\%%i\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" /v CAIL3of9" /d CAIL3of9.ttf /f)
```

Comment: You have typo's in your last line, and don't need to specify `/T`, because `REG_SZ` is the default value type. `reg.exe Add "\\%%i\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" /V "CAIL3of9" /D "CAIL3of9.ttf" /F`

Comment: @Compo - Thanks for the advise but this did not resolve the issue, I am still experiencing the same error: The network path was not found.

Comment: I did not post it as an answer, it was a comment. I specifically called them typos, I did not suggest that this was a solution for your network path error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('
  Type "C:\Users\adm-acoombes\Documents\scripts\AV-Update.txt"
') DO (
  robocopy "C:\Users\User1\Documents\FONT" "\\%%~i\c$\Windows\Test" *
  Reg Add "\\%%i\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" /v "CAIL3of9" /d "CAIL3of9.ttf" /f
)
```

You had several missing quotes around items which turned your value into another value.

You may need to change your `reg add` to `reg change`, or do a `reg del` followed by `reg add`

I changed your `for /f` to use `tokens=*` this is generally a matter of preference, but I believe it will not match any leading or trailing spaces, while using `"tokens=*"` will trim any leading white space from the items in your text file which may be at fault for the error you are seeing.